# Rename Amazon RDS table name to capital letter throws error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I imported my MySQL database tables to Amazon RDS. My problem is that my queries don't longer work and I get error that my table 'Folders' doesn't exists. The reason for that is that the table names are not all with lower casing, which causes the query to throw this error.

Is there a way to change the table name with one with uppercase using MySQL Workbench against Amazon RDS database. I tried using 'alter table', but it gives me an error "Selected name conflicts with exists table' when I try to rename to the same name and changing to capital letter. Any ideas how to solve this?

Maybe there is an option to tell Amazon RDS to ignore table name and table field's capitalization.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

modify your my.ini of mysql and change lower_case_table_names and restart mysql

```
lower_case_table_names=1
```

On Amazon RDS Parameter Group use the value '1'.

On regular MySQL installation, use the value '2'.

for more information you can go through with this nice article http://www.kulawik.de/blog/2011/02/lower_case_table_names/

Comment: it says ällowed values 0-1 in AMazon rds DB parameter group

Comment: I need to make it ignore the fields and table name casing

Comment: try with 0-1. it will ignore the table name

Comment: ok thanks, I will test it out. What about table fields (column) names, I need it to be ignored the casing too